# Ionic 2 video capturing

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

Can someone help me out where i can find or tell me how to implement video capturing for ionic 2 typescript.

I know about the picture taking which is simple but theirs no clear documentation on how to capture videos

Comment: Ionic 2 are the same as cordova plugins that you should be enough for you to find somethig working since you doesn't seem to have search enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Media Capture plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/media-capture/) 
To see the full documentation you should check the [git repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) of the plugin.
it is simple they provided the captureImage example, just use the `captureVideo(options)` method instead, you can find the options at the docs (the git repo docs) see 'CaptureVideoOptions' , you have the limit and the duration options.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture
    npm install --save @ionic-native/media-capture
```

videoplayer.html

```
   <ion-content padding>
   <button ion-button (click)="startrecording()">Start Video 
   Recording</button>
   <button ion-button (click)="selectvideo()">Select Video From 
   Gallery</button>
   <video #myvideo height="300" width="300" controls></video>
   </ion-content>
```

videoplayer.ts

```
    import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';
    import { Camera } from "@ionic-native/camera";
    .......
    @ViewChild('myvideo') myVideo: any;
    ......
    constructor(public camera:Camera, private mediaCapture: MediaCapture)
    {}
    startrecording() {
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo((videodata) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(videodata)); 
    })
    }

    selectvideo() {
    let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
    var options = {
    sourceType: 2,
    mediaType: 1
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((data) => {
    video.src = data;
    video.play();
   })
   }
  }
```

Source : http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-video-capture-and-playback/
         https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/